# how to pass parameter value in controller

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

I have this code

```
class UserController @Inject() (var factory:FactoryHandler) extends Controller {
}
```

FactoryHandler.scala

```
class FactoryHandler(s:String) {
}
```

how can I pass "s" parameter a value in UserController in playframework-2.4 please help I want to fill this parameter for further tasks

Answer (score 0):

Somehow changing the state of Injected object should be avoided as this Injected object can also be used by some other controller and modified state can lead to unnecessary bugs.

An ideal functional solution would be to change this injected class into case class or implement a copy method by yourself in class.

```scala
case class FactoryHandler(s: String)
```

```scala
class UserController @Inject() (var factory:FactoryHandler) extends Controller {

  val updatedFactory = factory.copy(s="Updated Value")

  furtherProcessing(updatedFactory)
}
```